# can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files

Tags: go

Here is the error message:

```
% go get     
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /Users/7yan00

% echo $GOPATH     
/Users/7yan00/Golang
```

How would you troubleshoot that error?

Answer (score 54):

Make sure you are using that command in the Go project source folder (like `/Users/7yan00/Golang/src/myProject`).

One alternative ([similar to this bug)](https://github.com/limetext/lime/issues/16) is to use the `-d` option (see [`go get` command](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies))

```
go get -d
```

> The `-d` flag instructs get to stop after downloading the packages; that is, it instructs get not to install the packages.

See if that helps in your case.

---

But more generally, as described [in this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/144t5mvrq4/go-nuts-go-get-code-google-com-p-go-text-doesnt-install-the-inner-packages):

> `go get` is for package(s), not for repositories.
>
> so if you want a specific package, say, `go.text/encoding`, then use

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding
```

> if you want all packages in that repository, use `...` to signify that:

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.text/...
```

Comment: @7yan00 in what folder were you when you ran that command? What version of go are you using?  On what OS? By "not moving", do you mean the go get command hangs, seems frozen and never returns?

Comment: I'm still having this problem myself.  I can't seem to `go get` any remote packages.  I always get `no buildable Go source files in `.

Answer (score 32):

You should check the `$GOPATH` directory. If there is an empty directory of the package name, `go get` doesn't download the package from the repository.

For example, If I want to get the `github.com/googollee/go-socket.io` package from it's github repository, and there is already an empty directory `github.com/googollee/go-socket.io` in the `$GOPATH`, `go get` **doesn't** download the package and then complains that there is no buildable Go source file in the directory. Delete any empty directory first of all.

Answer (score 13):

Another possible reason for the message:

> can't load package: .... : no buildable Go source files

Is when the source files being compiled have:

```
// +build ignore
```

In which case the files are ignored and not buildable as requested.This behaviour is documented at https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

Comment: This was the case for me -- the project uses build tags to include or exclude features from the binaries we build, and every file in the package had the `// +build myfeature` tag.  The workaround was to add a file in the package called dummy.go that contained nothing but the package declaration (i.e., `package myfeature`).

Comment: thanks for the hint, in my case it was 
`// +build !windows`

Comment: Similarly, I recently encountered a `// +build go1.9` which was causing this error when I was trying to build with go1.8

Comment: This is more proof that Go *really* needs to be much more descriptive and specific in it's error messages. Currently, it's very non-conducive to rapid development.

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this for my situation:

I had to specify a more specific sub-package to install.

Wrong:

```
go get github.com/garyburd/redigo
```

Correct:

```
go get github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want all packages in that repository, use `...` to signify that, like:

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.text/...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to download packages from mod

`go get -v all`

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error code and after checking my repository discovered that there were no go files but actually just more directories. So it was more of a red herring than an error for me.

I would recommend doing

> go env

and making sure that everything is as it should be, check your environment variables in your OS and check to make sure your shell (bash or w/e ) isn't compromising it via something like a .bash_profile or .bashrc file. good luck.