# "go get <package>" cannot find package

Tags: go

The command `go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto` doesn't seem to be working despite `GOPATH` set.

```
GOPATH="/Users/tmp/Documents/workspace/app/go"
```

I see a similar problem with other packages.

Error being read:

```
package github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto: cannot find package "github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/tmp/Documents/workspace/app/go/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto (from $GOPATH)
```

Running `go env` shows:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="" GOEXE="" GOHOSTARCH="amd64" GOHOSTOS="darwin" GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/tmp/Documents/workspace/app/go" GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go" GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What is the problem and how do I fix this? I haven't found anything on this online but this was working prior.

Comment: Does "/Users/tmp/Documents/workspace/app/go/src" exist? EDIT: Nevermind, see @Mark 's comment down below.

Comment: [github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto) doesn't exist, check the correct package name

Comment: My mistake: [gogo/protobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) does exist, and github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto is go gettable

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it is neccesery to delete the entire folder.

First you could try to use the `-u` flag ([go cmd doc](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)) to reinstall all the other dependencies.

> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network to check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.

go get supports also build flags to rebuild the package you could try `-a`:

> -a
>       force rebuilding of packages that are already up-to-date.

Comment: I tried the "-u" flag as well as the "-d" flag suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095004/cant-load-package-package-no-buildable-go-source-files. Neither worked. This is useful information, but did not solve the original problem. I did not try the "-a" command, and would need to replicate the error to see if it would work.

Answer (score 3):

After some fiddling, I found out that somehow source files within the src directory got deleted. I removed the **entire** folder and its contents, which caused the entire package to be reinstalled. This seems to have cleared the issue and resolved it.

I should note I ran into another error along the way of debugging:

> no buildable Go source files in /Users/tmp/Documents/workspace/app/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto

Again, this was all resolved after deleting the entire package in the source folder.

@Mark: One thing to note is that I was referencing the correct package name according to https://github.com/golang/protobuf.

Comment: Glad it's working. I thought the package name in your question was a typo, and didn't realise [gogo/protobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) was a port of the official [golang/protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)

Comment: Maybe not the case here, but this can also happen if a package owner renames part of the import path.  If "go get" worked before but not now, that is a possible reason.

Comment: It appears to me that go get will only download a package if it is missing.  I had an earlier version of go installed when I attempted to `go get` something and it failed.  After upgrading to go 12.10, I tried the `go get` again and it got further, but produced the package error in this question.  Deleting the folder worked.  -d -u -a did NOT work.