# How to remote debug with Delve debugger in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I have already asked, and got a very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058823/how-to-use-delve-debugger-in-visual-studio-code) for debugging locally with delve(golang debugger).

Now I am trying to remote debug with Delve using VS Code.

I have got a sample app mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go), and further github linked to source code [here](https://github.com/lukehoban/webapp-go/tree/debugging). Note: The debug project is in a branch called debugging.

Are you able to make it work?

I have also created/opened an issue in the [repo](https://github.com/lukehoban/webapp-go/issues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked:

1. Remove line 3 in launch.json "debugServer": 4711,"
2. Changed line 29 in launch.json ""host": "192.168.99.100" // Docker IP " to "127.0.0.1".

I was sure I tried this before, but apparently not bout at the same time.
Anyways happy go' lucky!

Comment: Can you please help me with any documentation or helper guides on how to configure remote debugging on go?

Comment: I eventually gave up, hoping it will be better/easier some day - that or rewrite my code. If you come by something good, please let me know.