# Remote debugging - Unverified breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, delve

Hope I can explain this right.

Update: I can confirm that `dlv debug -l 127.0.0.1:2345`  does work.
Therefore I must be in VsCode `launch.json`

Update: removed the panic. There was a different in go versions.
Now the debugger in VsCode is just not working, it says "Unverified breakpoint". But it works fine if I use `dlv` from terminal, if I am in the folder with the code.

I am trying to remote debug with [this](https://github.com/lukehoban/webapp-go/tree/debugging) sample code.

It works with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194562/how-to-remote-debug-with-delve-debugger-in-visual-studio-code) change.

Do you know what to do? I have tried to change the `launch.json` to `"program": "${workspaceRoot}",` to include the path like `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app",`.

Launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        },
        {
            // To remote debug in Docker, run the following before debugging:
            // # docker build -t webapp-go .
            // # docker run -d --name webapp-go --privileged -p 8080:8080 -p 2345:2345 webapp-go
            // # docker run -d --name webapp-go --privileged -p 8080:8080 -p 2345:2345 -v "${PWD%/*}/src/app/":/go/src/app webapp-go
            // And then each time you want to restart debugging:
            // # docker restart
            "name": "Remote debug in Docker",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "remote",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "remotePath": "/go/src/app",
            "port": 2345, // Port 
            "host": "127.0.0.1" // Docker IP
/*            "preLaunchTask": "docker" */ 
        }
    ]
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.6
RUN go get -u -v github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
EXPOSE 2345

# RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app
# WORKDIR /go/src/app
# VOLUME ["src/app2"]

VOLUME ["/go/src/app"]
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY src/app /go/src/app

RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["dlv", "debug", "--headless", "--listen=:2345", "--log"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem by adding the "trace" option to the `launch.json` (in VS Code)

```
    {
        "name": "Attach remote ",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "attach",
        "mode": "remote",
        "remotePath": "/home/me/goprojects/src/github.com/owner/project/package",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "xxxx.xyz",
        "trace":"log",

    }
```

Doing that revealed in the Debug Console that it was looking for the source file with the wrong path.  I realised that `remotePath` in the `launch.json` should be (for my setup at least) just `/home/me/goprojects/src/github.com/owner/project`

So, try adding trace and scrutinize the Debug Console

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get `delve` and `vscode` with `go` working for me by using `docker-compose`.

I use my `Dockerfile` to build the app as you do and just override some container attributes in my `docker-compose.yml`.

Here's how my `docker-compose.yml` looks :

```
version: '2'
services:
  my_app:
    build: .
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    entrypoint: dlv debug github.com/my_user/my_app -l 0.0.0.0:2345 --headless=true --log=true -- server
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/go/src/github.com/my_user/my_app
    ports:
      - "2345:2345"
    expose:
      - "2345"
```

And the `launch.json` file :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Remote Docker",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "/opt/go/src/github.com/my_user/my_app",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "192.168.99.100",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that since I'm on OS X the IP is what my `docker-machine ip default` prints. You can change it to `127.0.0.1` if this is what your `docker-machine ip` outputs.

On `docker-compose up`, `my_app` prints :

> my_app_1  | 2016/12/14 12:41:32 server.go:71: Using API v1
>
> my_app_1  | 2016/12/14 12:41:32 debugger.go:65: launching process with
>   args: [/opt/go/src/github.com/my_user/my_app/debug server]
>
> my_app_1  | API server listening at: [::]:2345

And after setting up some breakpoints and attaching the debugger it works.

Hope this helps!