# VS Code debug golang. Delve debuger

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with the Delve debuger in visual studio code. Debugging begins but nothing happens. There is only information in the console:

```
time="2018-06-23T16:35:55+02:00" level=info msg="launching process with args: [C:\\Users\\LenovoPC\\go\\src\\test\\debug]" layer=debugger
```

Configuration of launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {},
        "args": [],
        "showLog": true
    }
]
```

Comment: This may be because your workspace root path is different from the directory you have opened.

Comment: Have you tried to change the settings according to my answer and then run your code from `main.go`

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work. I wrote a post below

Comment: when you run debugger does it show any error in `PROBLEMS` or `DEBUG CONSOLE`

Comment: time="2018-06-23T21:01:55+02:00" level=info msg="launching process with args: [c:\\Users\\Lenovo\\go\\src\\hello\\debug]" layer=debugger

Comment: this is in debug windows. Problems window is clear

Comment: Go to `debug` icon add configuration select `Launch Package` and remove old configurations see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, it also does not work. I've tried everything with the launch.json file already

Comment: The issue is with the new Go version.
References
https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/1245 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1752

Comment: This `launch.json` and setup worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746989/2175188.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on how you install delve it will either end up in your PATH or
>   GOPATH/bin. If dlv binary is in your GOPATH/bin and this GOPATH is not
>   set as an environment variable, then make sure your PATH points to
>   this GOPATH/bin so that the Go extension can find the dlv binary.

Try to change the directory to filename to run the project from `main.go` of your project folder as

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure $GOPATH is set (e.g. as ~/.go)
On terminal run the command

```
go env
```

to check for `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` variables to see if delve is synchronized with them

For more information Checkout [How to configure Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/linux/install.md)