# How to build Golang blog from github?

Tags: windows, github, go

Im not very good with Go and I am having a lot of problems with understanding how common website features are made, so I thought it would be good to see a real example. I tried building https://github.com/golang/blog but its not working.

My gopath is apparently C:/Users/me/go as it should be.

*Edit Except if I run  cd $GOPATH/src, it says C:\src doesnt exist, it looks in C: not C:/Users

Method 1. (running go get -u golang.org/x/blog)
I open Powershell and run that in my Users/me/go/src directory and it says:

```
can't load package: package golang.org: no Go files in 
C:\Users\me\go\src\golang.org
```

But it does download the source files. So its basically this step?
'u can manually git clone the repository to $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/blog.'

Then I dont know where to run go build or what to run. I tried 
    go build -o blog.exe ./blog

and it says
    can't load package: package blog: cannot find package "blog" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\blog (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Users\me\go\src\blog (from $GOPATH)

I tried running the same command in different directories of the project and doesnt work.

Comment: On Windows, replace `$GOPATH` (Linux) with `%GOPATH%` (Windows).

Comment: Yeah sorry I just realised this too, its kind of weird how a lot of documentation and stuff is for Linux cause its what actual servers run on and what not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions. (Note that I am a Linux user, so there may be some discrepancies with the Windows commands below. You may want to follow these directions: http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/12/easy-go-programming-setup-for-windows/ to setup the `GOROOT` environment variable.)

1. For method 1, the `-u` flag tells `go` to *update* the source code. Since you haven't downloaded it before, it lets you know with the error you see. What you want to run is `go get golang.org/x/blog`.
2. To build the package, you first want to change the directory (`cd`) to the package root, so `cd %GOPATH%\src\golang.org\x\blog` or `cd C:\Users\me\go\src\golang.org\x\blog`. Next, you want to run `go build`. Then, you can run the output file, which should automatically be named `blog.exe`.

Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: Alright ill go through your question now, thankyou. I upvoted but I dont have 15 points yet.

Comment: Ok I did it and the install on windows thing was very helpful. With the package I had some problems still and I fixed them! I used go get golang.org/x/blog... with the three dots which apparently signifies get the whole repository (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095004/cant-load-package-package-no-buildable-go-source-files).
Then I had problem where the two .css files werent being loaded because its localhost and the directory were wrong and the github repo has no css so I copied it from the actual site and made css files where localhost expects to find them. Thank you for helping me

Comment: Wow this is actually so cool, I have the whole golang.org website locally now including the playground, docs, and packages.